# Alternative to Rtmp and red5 for Iphone application

Tags: iphone, red5, rtmp

I am using Red5 + RTMP in a client-server flash application.

There aren't audio/video streams in my application. RTMP is used to transfer messages from app to server and back.

Now I need to develop the application for iPhone:

1. is there any RTMP implementation on iPhone?
2. If not, how could I solve this problem? Is there any alternative to RTMP on iPhone?

And most important question: could it be solved without rewriting whole server part of application? (Red5 + RTMP)

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I am also looking for same thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to pass "messages" and no a/v, might I suggest using a REST service or something similar such as doing GET or POST requests containing your "message" encoded in some form? Such as JSON or BASE64?

Comment: No encoding needed if SSL is used and certificate verification is done. However additional security would not hurt, especially if the goal of the app is to be a very secure for text communications.